# Java replace string string by other string

Tags: java

I want to replace 1 by 1Min, 5 by 5Min, 10 by 10Min, 15 by 15Min,60 by 1Hour, 360 by 6Hours etc.

How can I do it in 1 statement.

```
String str = "15";
String newStr = str.replace("1", "1Min").replace("5", "5Mins").replace("10", "10Mins").replace("15", "15Mins").replace("30", "30Mins").replace("60", "1Hr").replace("120", "2Hrs").replace("240", "4Hrs").replace("480", "8Hrs").replace("720", "12Hrs").replace("1440", "24Hrs");
```

If I try this, i get '1Min5Mins' because it replaces 1 and then 5.

This could be a stupid question, I can do it with switch or `if, else-if`. just wondering can this be done in 1 line code.
Thanks

Comment: What do you do with 80?

Comment: Nothing... I know there will be only these values (1,5,10,15,30,60,120,240,480,600,720,1440)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
String str = "15";
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(str);
if (minutes < 60)
    str += "Mins";
else
    str = (minutes/60) + "Hrs";
```

but be aware that `Integer.parseInt()` will throw an exception if you try to parse anthing else than a number. This can be inaccurate if the hours are not exact (365 will be replaced by 6 hours although it's 6 hours and 5 minutes)

Here's the 1-liner:

```
str = Integer.parseInt(str) < 60 ? str+"Mins" : (Integer.parseInt(str)/60) + (Integer.parseInt(str)/60 == 1 ? "Hr" : "Hrs");
```

although this would be more readable with a 2-liner:

```
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(str);
str = minutes < 60 ? str+"Mins" : (minutes/60) + (minutes/60 == 1 ? "Hr" : "Hrs");
```

Comment: This is not 1 line code sir :) I know I can do it this way.

Comment: @Ana i'll write you a 1 liner but it's not very pretty then ;)

Comment: Great... Thanks for this, i think this is more elegant :)

Comment: @Ana more importantly it's a lot more readable and should also be way faster!

Comment: But for 60 it will give 60Min instead of 1 Hr

Comment: @Ana oh forgive me... instead of `<= 60` it should be `<60`... i'll correct that

Comment: No,it will then return 1Hrs which is not correct either :) it should be 1Hr

Comment: You'll have to chain some '?' operators then... see my update ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the one-liner for you:

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\b1\\b", "1Min").replaceAll("\\b5\\b", "5Mins").replace("10", "10Mins").replace("15", "15Mins").replace("30", "30Mins").replace("60", "1Hr").replace("120", "2Hrs").replace("240", "4Hrs").replace("480", "8Hrs").replace("720", "12Hrs").replace("1440", "24Hrs");
```

With the regex [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Was too lazy to finish it till the end.

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ana np, pls go ahead and mark this as an answer so the lazy way of coding shows on top :)

Answer (score 2):

You could adjust for the earlier replacements when looking for later replacements:

```
String str = "15";
String newStr = str.replace("1", "1Min").replace("5", "5Mins").replace("1Min0", "10Mins").replace("1Min5Mins", "15Mins").replace("30", "30Mins")
                       .replace("60", "1Hr").replace("1Min20", "2Hrs").replace("240", "4Hrs").replace("480", "8Hrs").replace("720", "12Hrs")
                       .replace("1Min440", "24Hrs");
```

This way, the `1` in `15` will first be replaced by `1Min`, then the `5` will be replaced by `5Mins` and then `1Min5Mins` will be replaced by `15Mins`.

It is not the most elegant solution though, but it is the only way I can think of to replace everything in one line.

Comment: I really like what you are doing there :D +1 for nice-ugly code ;)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a one liner but it is a dynamic approach to your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String test = "15 20 60 360";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
        if(temp >= 60)
        {
            int temp1 = temp / 60;
            test = test.replaceFirst(("" + temp), ("" + temp1 + "Hour(s)"));
        }
        else
        {
            test = test.replaceFirst(("" + temp), ("" + temp + "Min(s)"));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Output:

```
15Min(s) 20Min(s) 1Hour(s) 6Hour(s)
```